# Flutter camera plugin prevent orientation change?

Tags: flutter, camera, rotation, locking, orientation

Using the latest version `0.8.1`, is there a way to prevent orientation change? I have locked the device orientation using `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);` but if I rotate the device to landscape, the camera also attempts to rotate and the preview looks compressed. A good example would be the instagram camera, which is locked to portrait mode. If you rotate your device the preview doesn't move at all.

Answer (score 8):

You can apply lock on capture orientation this will also used for app being crashed during camera initialisation

```
await _cameraController.initialize();
await _cameraController.lockCaptureOrientation();
```

Comment: this is the correct order of calling those methods and it is important for it to be like that, not the other way around, or it won't work... can confirm for version `0.9.4+3`

Answer (score 1):

I must have missed it in the documentation (or it's been left out), but as of version `0.7.0` there is a lock method:

`<CameraController>.lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation);`

Answer (score -2):

```
Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(orientation == Orientation.portrait
    ? [
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]
    : [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      ]);
```